# Masking Basic Auth header when using CURL to trigger remote jenkins job

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, curl, .netrc

I want to trigger remote Jenkins job from my container(k8s).

Currently, I'm using:

`curl -k -X POST -u $USER:$JENKINS_TOKEN "${JENKINS_URL}/job/{$JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters?token=12345"`

But this information($USER,$JENKINS_TOKEN) is displayed in ArgoUI, is there any secure/other way to save credentials for remote trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following.

Save the password in a file called `password-file` and read from that

```
curl -k -X POST -u $USER:$(cat .password-file)"${JENKINS_URL}/job/{$JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters?token=12345"
```

Accept credentials from the STDIN.

```
curl -k -X POST "${JENKINS_URL}/job/{$JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters?token=12345" -K- <<< "--user $USER:$JENKINS_TOKEN"
```

You can also try using `--netrc-file` option with curl where you can store the username and password in a file itself.

file

```
machine JENKINS_HOST login USERNAME password PASSWORD
```

Curl Command

```
curl -k -X POST --netrc-file my-password-file "${JENKINS_URL}/job/{$JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters?token=12345"
```